# Kubernetes deployment from AWS ECR failed with status code: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I want to deploy image from AWS ECR into Kubernetes. I use this command to get the token:

```
TOKEN=`aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | cut -d' ' -f6`                                                                                                                                       
kubectl delete secret -n default --ignore-not-found awsecr-cred                                                                                                                                           
kubectl create secret -n default docker-registry awsecr-cred --docker-server=123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test-gateway --docker-username=AWS --docker-password=$TOKEN --namespace=default
```

Into pod logs I get error:

```
Failed to pull image "123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test-gateway:0.0.1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test-gateway:0.0.1": failed to resolve reference "123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test-gateway:0.0.1": pulling from host 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com failed with status code [manifests 0.0.1]: 401 Unauthorized
```

When I run `aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | cut -d' ' -f6` I get token. Do you know where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What does your deployment yaml look like? You need to specify `imagePullSecrets` for the pod to use. It should look something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

You can find a full example [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-pod-that-uses-your-secret).